# jQuery custom content scroller plugin with iframe - probably CSS problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to use the [Malihu jQuery custom content scroller plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/).

I've manage to get something working based off the demos provided with the plugin but when I try to adapt it to my existing code I run into problems. I think it has something to do the with the height, width and overflow attributes in the css. I've been playing around with them but am getting nowhere.

If someone could help identify the differences between the working example and the broken one that'd be great.

---

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XYd7G/

Broken Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tKnz7/2/ - I can get it to replace the scrollbar but it doesn't seem to detect the overflow.

Broken Example iFrame: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4gyDL/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/7NgG8/4/ - I'm trying create something exactly like this except replacing the content scrollbar.

---

JS

```
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
        autoHideScrollbar:true,
        theme:"light-thin"
    });
```

---

HTML + CSS of Working Example:

HTML

```
<h1>iframe demo</h1>
    <!-- content block -->
    <div class="content">
        <iframe src="http://slipsum.com/" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="1000" frameborder="0">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    color:#eee; 
    background:#222; 
    font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; 
    font-size:13px; 
    line-height:20px;
}

.content{margin:40px; width:1040px; height:500px; overflow:auto;}
```

---

Relevant HTML + CSS of Broken Example:

HTML

```
<div id="sidebar" class="open">
        <div class="nav">
                <div class="tr">
                        <div class="top">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="link"><img src="_images/attributes/user.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="link"><img src="_images/attributes/contribute.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="link"><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="link"><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="link"><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="link"><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tr">
                        <div class="middle">
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tr">
                        <div class="bottom">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="link"><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="link"><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="link"><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="link"><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                                    <li class="current"><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <iframe src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/4gyDL/2/show/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>

<div id="dummy-column"></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
#sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 20em;
    z-index:2;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #303030;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -30px 0 30px -10px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -30px 0 30px -10px #222;
    box-shadow: inset -30px 0 30px -10px #222;
    -webkit-transition:margin 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:margin 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:margin 1s ease-in;
    transition:margin 1s ease-in;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.nav{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:3em;
    float: right;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    border-left: 2px groove #454545;    
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -10px 0 10px -10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -10px 0 10px -10px #000;
    box-shadow: inset -10px 0 10px -10px #000;
}

/* iframe stuff is here */

.content {
    height:100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 16.875em;
    float: right;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#eee;
    font-family: "Georgia", Sans-Serif;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* end of iframe stuff */
```

---

iframe HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">

        <div class="content">
            <p class="title">MISSION CONTROL</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="heading">Recent Changes</li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><ul>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                </ul></li>
                <li class="heading">Formatting</li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><ul>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                </ul></li>
                <li class="heading">Categorise</li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><ul>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                </ul></li>
                <li class="heading">Categorise</li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><ul>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                    <li>Content Sub-Menu</li>
                </ul></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

iframe CSS:

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%}
#sidebar {
    text-align: center;
    width: 16.875em;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #333333;
}


.content {
    width: 16.875em;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4gyDL/3/

Comment: Not quite but applying the scrollbar on the iframe content I haven't thought of. That might work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the y - scrollbar in the i-frame inner content
and then use

```
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:hidden;
```

I made a simplified example at http://jsfiddle.net/tKnz7/4/

I cant get the Malihu scroller plugin to work on jsfiddle.net, problem upvoted.

Comment: I need the a iframe to be 100% window height however. I tried modifying you code and replacing the plugin links. And I've got this the scroll bar is there but it doesn't seem to correctly detect the overflow. http://jsfiddle.net/XYd7G/

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise what you did to the iframe inner. This is close enough to what I'm after: http://jsfiddle.net/XYd7G/1/